# encrypt and decrypt using AES Algorithms

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

I found a tutorial on encrypting and decrypting but I encounter a slight problem trying to implement the tutorial. Im wondering if its permanent or not but there is a line `String seedValue = "This Is MySecure";` when I try to change the text to other text im having problem problems in decrypting. Is this code unchangeable in this code I was thinking if I could use it to encrypt and decrypt password. here is the code.

(Using AESHelper class, full code found [here](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-example-for-encrypt-and-decrypt.html).)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String seedValue = "This Is MySecure";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String normalText = "VIJAY";
        String normalTextEnc;

        try{
            normalTextEnc = AESHelper.encrypt(seedValue, normalText);
            String normalTextDec = AESHelper.decrypt(seedValue, normalTextEnc);
            TextView txe = new TextView(this);
            txe.setTextSize(14);
            txe.setText("Normal Text ::" + normalText + " \n Encrypted Value :: " + normalTextEnc + " \n Decrypted value :: " + normalTextDec);
            setContentView(txe);
        }catch(Exception e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Was able to implement both encrypt and decrypt but I get another problem that I don't understand why it occurs and how to fix it.

The errors says `03-21 05:25:08.554: E/Exception(2109): pad block corrupted` i got the code from this site [here](http://kvandroidapp.blogspot.com/2012/11/example-for-encrypt-and-decrypt-using.html)

**UPDATE:**

Pad Block fixed another one came it says:

> 03-24 02:31:33.131: E/Exception(1308): error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

**UPDATE:**
this is my code and i follow as adviced but still when i try to decrypt the encrypted and vice versa enrcypt the decrypted i get exception.

```
package com.sample.camera;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.util.Base64;

public class EncodeDecodeAES {



    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    private final static int JELLY_BEAN_4_2 = 17;

    private final static byte[] key = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };




    // static {

    // Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    // }



    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());

        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());

        String fromHex = toHex(result);

        String base64 = new String(Base64.encodeToString(fromHex.getBytes(), 0));

        return base64;


    }




    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {

        byte[] seedByte = seed.getBytes();

        System.arraycopy(seedByte, 0, key, 0, ((seedByte.length < 16) ? seedByte.length : 16));

        String base64 = new String(Base64.decode(encrypted, 0));

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seedByte);

        byte[] enc = toByte(base64);

        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);

        return new String(result);


    }




    public static byte[] encryptBytes(String seed, byte[] cleartext) throws Exception {

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());

        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext);

        return result;


    }




    public static byte[] decryptBytes(String seed, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());

        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, encrypted);

        return result;


    }




    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {

        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); // , "SC");

        SecureRandom sr = null;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= JELLY_BEAN_4_2) {

            sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");


        } else {

            sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");


        }

        sr.setSeed(seed);

        try {

            kgen.init(256, sr);

            // kgen.init(128, sr);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            // Log.w(LOG, "This device doesn't suppor 256bits, trying 192bits.");

            try {

                kgen.init(192, sr);


            } catch (Exception e1) {

                // Log.w(LOG, "This device doesn't suppor 192bits, trying 128bits.");

                kgen.init(128, sr);


            }

        }

        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();

        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

        return raw;


    }




    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); // /ECB/PKCS7Padding", "SC");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);

        return encrypted;


    }




    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); // /ECB/PKCS7Padding", "SC");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        return decrypted;


    }




    public static String toHex(String txt) {

        return toHex(txt.getBytes());


    }




    public static String fromHex(String hex) {

        return new String(toByte(hex));


    }




    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {

        int len = hexString.length() / 2;

        byte[] result = new byte[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)

            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).byteValue();

        return result;

    }



    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)

            return "";

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {

            appendHex(result, buf[i]);

        }
        return result.toString();

    }




    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {

        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));


    }




}
```

Comment: Did you encrypt the text with the same seedValue?  You can't change seedValue to something new after.  it's your password.

Comment: what i did is change the seedValue and set the normal to the text in the password field its working fine but i get error in decrypt part.it says bad decrypt.

Comment: Still you did this change **before** encrypting whatever you are trying to decrypt now?

Comment: this is the actual value..String seedValue = "This Is MySecure"; this is the real value i change it before to something like String seedValue = "Encyprt My Password"; it did encrypt but it did not decyrpt because on the decrypt line i get error saying bad dcrypt. is this unchangeable?

Comment: The seedValue should be completely changable.  It just uses the bytes of the string to generate an entryption key.  You'll probably need to post more details (stack trace) of the error to find help.

Comment: @NameSpace any idea on 03-21 05:25:08.554: E/Exception(2109): pad block corrupted error?

Comment: @HakHak Based on the updated code, the issue lies with the attempt to create an encryption key by seeding a SecureRandom instance. This is unreliable and can cause different results (thus different encryption/decryption keys) causing your error. To derive a key from a string please consider using a proper KDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I missed something your issue lies with the actual padding procedure of data input.

AES is a **block cipher**, which means it works on chunks of data at a time. For AES the block size happens to be 128-bit or 16 bytes. If you data is not a multiple of 16 bytes you'll get a exception when AES tries to process the last block.

To solve this issue cipher padding schemes were invented. A cipher padding scheme essentially "pads" your data in a way such that it becomes a multiple of 16 bytes, allowing AES to process the last block without issue. The *de facto* standard padding scheme for AES is PKCS#5 or PKCS#7 padding (they're the same thing with different names).

The problem essentially lies on the line:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

from the `AESHelper` class.

Calling the getInstance() method with only a algorithm name (as opposed to *algorithm/mode/padding*) causes java to **infer** a specific cipher mode and padding scheme. This can be seen under *Creating a Cipher object* in the *Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) Reference Guide* denoted below:

> If just a transformation name is specified, the system will determine if there is an implementation of the requested transformation available in the environment, and if there is more than one, returns there is a preferred one.
>
> If no mode or padding is specified, provider-specific default values for the mode and padding scheme are used. For example, the SunJCE provider uses ECB as the default mode, and PKCS5Padding as the default padding scheme for DES, DES-EDE and Blowfish ciphers.

again, the same statement is visible in **android's** Cipher javadoc page:

> If mode and/or padding values are omitted, provider specific default values will be used.

What you want here is:

> AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding

although arguably I would say the above isn't secure and the following should be used:

> AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

coupled with random IV generation but thats a different story for another time.

Change the line:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

to

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

should solve your issue.

Comment: i think i understand what you mean i will try to do as you said +1 for you mate one question will this line stay the same SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

Comment: pad block fixed but another came it is 03-24 02:31:33.131: E/Exception(1308): error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt any idea how to fix this

Comment: @HakHak Thats a generic exception for invalid decryption. Bad data (corrupt ciphertext data), bad key, wrong padding scheme, etc can all cause that exception. Without anything else, its hard to tell where the issue lies.

Comment: what do you suggest i do to resolve the issue should i change everything?change the code for encrypt or decrypt?or i am just doing something wrong that us why i am getting the exception?

Comment: @HakHak My solution above, was it applied to both encryption **and** decryption? Both need it... If you're still having issues, I suggest you edit your question to reflect the state of your current working (new) code.